# htaccess virtual subdomains and parameters

Tags: .htaccess

i have an htaccess for creating virtual subdomains which working fine

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|JPG)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  virtialsubdomain.php?subdomain=%1 [L]
```

With the above i can see for example virtual1.domain.com, virtual2.domain.com etc

I want to extend the htaccess so i can pass 2 parameters for paging and sorting

Example

```
virtual1.domain.com/p/3 show page 3 
virtual1.domain.com/sort/id,asc show results sort by id asc
virtual1.domain.com/sort/id,asc/p/3 the combination of 2 above
```

For other pages in the www.domain.com i have rules that achieve that

```
RewriteRule category/([^.]+)/sort/([^.]+)/p/([0-9]+)?$ /file.php?id=$1&sort=$2&p=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule category/([^.]+)/sort/([^.]+)?$ /file.php?id=$1&sort=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule category/([^.]+)/p/([0-9]+)?$ /file.php?id=$1&p=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But i really dont know how to write the rules when comes the virtual subdomains

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I always separate things out first. Make all request to subdomains map to the subdomains folder like so:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdomains/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /subdomains/$1 [L]
```

Then in /subdomains/ you create a separate htaccess to do the paging and sorting rules.

```
RewriteBase /subdomains
RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]+)$  index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sort/([^/]+)(/p/([0-9]+))?$  index.php?sort=$1&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```